# Amazon RDS: OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on rds.amazonaws.com (110)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-rds

I have set up an Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) with a MySQL database and I'm trying to connect it with my django application but I'm getting the above error. My database settings in `settings.py` are as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': config('db_engine'),
    'NAME': config('db_name'),
    'USER': config('db_user'),
    'PASSWORD': config('db_password'),
    'HOST': config('db_host'),
    'PORT': config('db_port')
}
```

}

and my database environment variables are as follows:

```
db_engine=django.db.backends.mysql
db_name=stagingdatabase
db_user=staginguser
db_password=stagingpassword
db_host=somestagingname.somestagingid.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
db_port=3306
```

I know the port is correct, which is the solution for most cases having these types of errors. All other variables are correct as well.

I can't ping somestagingname.somestagingid.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com even though its status is available, so there must be an issue in how I setup the RDS:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the network information for this use case? From where are you executing the django code? Have you enable rds accesses in the security group?

Comment: @RafaelAguilar, The code is ran on a live ubuntu server with nginx. I've added the db_host on ALLOWED_HOSTS as well. Is that what you meant? Also, I didn't know I needed to enable some kind of rds access in the security group.

Comment: I guess what Nginx is running in a EC2 machines. Right?.

Comment: Also, ALLOWED_HOST is a django parameter to control de names to access the web server, not related with DB.

Comment: Regarding security access between DB and EC2 machine there are some configuration checks you would need to do: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if it works, to redact previous as an answer.

Comment: @RafaelAguilar, it was an issue with the security group. You can post it as an answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a network issue, the Django server is not able to reach the database, this can happen for diverse issues:

- They are in different and unconnected VPNs or Networks.
- The security group for the EC2 machine where Django is running is not allowing this outbound traffic to this network-port combination.
- The security group in the RDS is not allowing inbound traffic from the network where the EC2 machine is for the 3306 port.

If you are in an sceneario where you are using the default networking provided with the AWS Account it is likely to discard the first scenario. Also, by default all outgoing traffic is allowed for EC2 machines.

So my best suggestion would to start checking on the security group that controls inbound traffic to your RDS.

For more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html